# Geany intellisense like functionality for C++

Tags: c++, geany

Is there a plugin for Geany that will provide an Intellisense-like functionality for C++? Like when you press ctrl + spacebar all functions/members of the included libraries are shown or listed as hints? or when you type a few letters all methods or variables starting with those letters are listed?

I know there's code completion in Geany, but its not like Intellisense of VS, where all members/functions of the linked libraries are show when you press ctrl + spacebar.

Comment: How is this different from [your earlier question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12540792/geany-hint-list-for-classes-in-linked-libraries)? Is this not essentially the same?

Answer (score 2):

You have a couple of options.

If you have the file open where the class is declared, then code completion works out of the box.
So suppose you are in class Patient, and it calls Treatment->getActivitiesForPatient(this), and if you have the Treatment class open, it works.

There is also the option to create a tags file in Geany, see 
http://www.geany.org/Download/Extras#tags. (Note that for windows 7 the directory to put your tags file is AppData/Roaming/geany/tags.)

An example how to create a tags file:

```
$ your/application/root>geany -g /tmp/mytagsfile.tags $(find . -type f -name '*.php')
```

Answer (score 1):

I use Geany and I don't really know about anything like this, though I might be wrong. But if you're working on Linux, you might want to check IDEs like MonoDevelop (I used it for C# on Linux but it supports C++ too, and it's like MS Visual Studio) or Eclipse, which is mainly for Java but has a C/C++ and a Fortran extension as well. I know they exist, but again, I never used the C++ one, which is this one:

[www.eclipse.org/cdt/](http://www.eclipse.org/cdt/)

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion, but I think I'll stick for Geany for now. Even though its code completion sucks, it's still lightweight and very fast. I just hope the developers of it will find some time to improve its code completion, it's the only feature that Geany lacks.

Comment: You know, I don't think I've ever seen intellisense-like systems outside of IDEs. I think it's because you do need to have a grasp of what the 'project' is in order to include the most useful autocompletion - that is, the autocompletion of library classes, or the ones you generated yourself. I think it would be great too, but in the end, Geany wouldn't probably be so lightweight and fast if it had to take care of that too...!

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion the fastest code completition (like intellisense) ever implemented is the one of QtCreator. It's really fast also in big codebases